# Sending a server generated message back to client through Flask-SocketIO-Kafka

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, apache-kafka, flask-socketio

I have a message that is generated in the server side.

According to the [flask-socketio doc](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can send serverside generated message back to client through `socketio.emit` or `socketio.send`

The message is at the Kafka consumer

```
topicReply = 'botReply'
consumerReply = KafkaConsumer(topicReply, value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii')))
for message in consumerReply:
    fromConsumer(message.value)
```

I send this message to `server.py` through simply calling the `fromConsumer` method as seen above.

Then in my `server.py`, I call `socketio.emit` to send it to the client

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

def fromConsumer(msg):
    socketio.emit('reply', msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Then on my client side javascript

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1000/');
socket.on('reply', function(msg) {
        console.log('Received reply');
    console.log(msg)
    });
```

This should show me the received reply message in the browser javascript console but I don't see anything.

What am I missing? Please suggest.

Comment: Are you running your server on port 1000 or 5000? The SocketIO code does not have any explicit ports, which means it will go on 5000, but your clients connects to 1000. You may want to look at the console in your browser to see if there are any errors due to this or other possible problems.

Comment: @Miguel I run the flask app as `sudo FLASK_APP=server.py flask run --port=1000` so it is running on port 1000

Comment: Ok. Then I would add logging on the server and client to trace where is this event getting lost. I honestly don't see anything wrong at first sight.

Comment: @Miguel I just tested this w/o kafka and it works. But when I add the Kafka producer-consumer route, it doesn't work. Somewhere the kafka-flask-socketio route is breaking and I am not sure where it its.

Comment: Are you using eventlet or gevent for this server? If yes, have you monkey patched the standard library? Kafka likely requires that.

Comment: @Miguel no I am not using eventlet or gevent

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have them installed in your virtual environment? These frameworks are automatically used if found installed.